# How to auto focus an input which is inside semantic ui react dropdown

Tags: javascript, reactjs, semantic-ui-react

I am trying to autofocus an input which is inside semantic ui react dropdown by using ref but for some reason it is not working. Also input should be auto-focused when dropdown is opened.
Here is the code sandbox link. Thank you very much
https://codesandbox.io/s/semantic-ui-example-forked-5wrlp?file=/example.js

Comment: Based on semantic-ui doc: https://react.semantic-ui.com/modules/dropdown/#types-search-in-menu. `Dropdown state is not fully managed when using the subcomponent API. The shorthand props API fully manages state but needs to be extended to support the markup shown here.`

Comment: So it is not possible i assume?

Comment: It seems that it is not possible!

Comment: @MajidM. it is possible.

Answer (score 0):

This is possible without using Refs. Note that SUIR has a Ref component, but in this case, the Ref would still not get the inner input tag, it would get the wrapping div.

You can use the `autoFocus` prop on the input to make the input focus when rendered. Note that this will only work if you prevent the contents of the dropdown from rendering when the dropdown is not open. Otherwise the input would get focus as soon as it rendered, even if the dropdown was not focused.

I updated your codepen with an example of this working. One other thing to note is you will likely need to use the controlled component pattern in order to conditionally render the dropdown menu if the component is not open, and this means adding all of the other open/close functionality yourself with the appropriate handlers.

https://codesandbox.io/s/semantic-ui-example-autofocus-input-in-dropdown-wxxd1